# Google App Engine. How to make synchronized actions using memcache or datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

My main goal is to be able to have some synchronized method that shouldn't be accessed by other threads until it is finished.
If I had usual VM - I would mark this method as synchronized.
But in GAE I have multiple instances.
All posts that I read about this say that I should use memcache or datastore.
But how exactly ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually the answer is redesign the function so it doesn't need to be globally synchronized.  Even if you manage to synchronize  it, it's a single bottleneck.

You're probably best off to implement it on a backend; you can specify a single backend, and make your function call a request to the backend.  You can also use memcache or the datastore as semaphore, but all of those are going to give you poor performance.

Comment: **You can also use memcache or the datastore as semaphore** How exactly ?

Comment: Please, don't advice me not to want to have synronized actions. This is very often case and it works perfectly in usual applications.

Comment: The logically you know how to implement semaphores. You might want to use CAS with memcache if going that way. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/overview#Using_Compare_and_Set_in_Python

Comment: @boraldomaster My advice for you to not synchronize is in fact the usual case on a distributed platform like GAE.  In most cases there's no need to synchronize functions, as long as you use transactional datastore operations.  You won't find much discussion of synchronized functions on GAE because it's a bad idea and it's definitely not the usual case for this platform.  You're going to have lots of problems on GAE if you don't design around the platform's behaviors.

Comment: If you really want to implement your own synchronization, there's examples online of using memcache as a mutex: http://xion.org.pl/2011/12/10/synchronization-through-memcache/

On the other hand, memcache never guarantees anything, so I suspect this is likely to fail at some points.  You could consider using datastore transactions in a similar manner, but it's going to be incredibly slow.

Comment: Use of "memcache" does not appear useful, because memcache can be voided at any time (see reference: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/best-practices-for-app-engine-memcache )

Comment: I'm a little frustrated by "redesign the function so it doesn't need to be globally synchronized" do you have any information on how to achieve this? I have several people all logged into the same database (an appointment booking system) then how can I ensure that we avoid double booking or overwriting each others changes if we can't guarantee the integrity of the data on the database? Yesterday one of my customers made a manual payment at the same time as an automated payment was processed and the manual payment overwrote the automatic payment, luckily I could track back through paypal!

Comment: @johnvdenley: If you require global transactions, use a SQL DB instead of the Datastore.  I've recorded payments on the Datastore before, but SQL is probably a better technology.  If you use Datastore, design it in such a way that you can't overwrite ie, write everything into separate keys, with timestamps, so even if writes happen at the same time, a later query will identify that two writes occurred.  With the appointment booking, you might try to identify the basic resource that you might be blocked on, like a room, and use that as your ancestor so you can have transactions around the room.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't use that kind of synchronization a lot.
Once I did. It seems to work pretty well.
Here is an example

```
String syncKey = "Sync:" + req.getRequestURI();
boolean lockAcquired = false;
try {
  lockAcquired = acquireLock(syncKey, 5000L);
  if (!lockAcquired) {
    return;
  }
  // do something here

} finally {
  if (lockAcquired) {
    memcacheService.delete(syncKey);
  }
}


public boolean acquireLock(String syncKey, long maxwait) {
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  while (true) {
    if (memcacheService.increment(syncKey, 1L, 0L) == 1L) {
      return true;
    }
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start > maxwait) {
      return false;
    }
    try {
      Thread.sleep(100L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Usually I use more simpler synchronization. It gives me opportunity to run some piece of code only once.

```
final long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / (60L * 1000L); // expire every minute
if (memcacheService.increment("VoteRemoveOldTask" + now, 1L, 1L) == 1L) {
  QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().add(
      TaskOptions.Builder.withDefaults().url(VoteRemoveOldTask.URL));
}
```

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/best-practices-for-app-engine-memcache for reasons why memcache cannot be relied upon.

Comment: Agree. But at the same time that is OK for simple cases.