# Auto increment entity ids from given range in datastore appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

We are developing an application in which entity ids for tables must be in incremental order starting from 1 to so on, for each namespace.

We came across [allocateIdRange](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#allocateIdRange-com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyRange-), [allocateIds](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#allocateIds-java.lang.String-long-) methods in [DatastoreService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService) interface but these ids must be assigned manually and will not be assigned by DatastoreService itself. Assigning ids manually may leads to synchronization problems with multiple instances.

Can anyone provide me suggestions to overcome this problem?

We are using objectify 3.0 for DatastoreService operations.

Comment: I suggest you reconsider the design constraint of sequential ids. Otherwise you need to design a locking/synchronising mechanism and work allocated ids.  However this question is not really suitable for SO, its about strategy and is a very broad question.  It will probably get closed.

Comment: There are [many patterns](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=app+engine+atomic+counter&oq=app+engine+atomic+counter&ie=UTF-8) for *atomic counters* using Datastore but unless it's really the only option, you can probably find a more appropriate solution that doesn't rely on sequential IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Tim Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201324/tim-hoffman) and [tx802](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668204/tx802) when they say you should reconsider your design regarding sequential ids. However a while ago i had to implement something very similar because the customer forced us to use sequential and uninterrupted numbers for order numbers (for unclear reasons). Regardless we complied with the customers wishes by using [sharding counters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters)(link contains full code sample) for the order numbers. Sharding counters work like this:

- You create a couple of entities of the same kind in your datastore which are just counter values
- The actual value is calculated by querying all entities of that kind and summarizing their values
- When you wish to increase the value, one of the entities is randomly chosen and incremented
- The current counter value may be cached in memcache for improved performance

Why does this work:

- As you may know you have a restriction/limitation of 1 transaction per second and entity group in the datastore. Therefor you shard the counter into multiple entities and avoid this limitation. The more traffic you expect, the more shards you're going to need. Luckily you can increase the count of shards at any time.
- We also know that writes are slow in comparison to reads. Therefor building the sum of all shards is a fast operation while increasing a single shard value (write) is slow, which doesn't bother us when using sharding counters because we have sufficient time.

**Summarized:**
You can use sharding counters for sequential ids. If you can avoid the whole sequential id dilemma it would be a better solution though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We found the following link useful to achieve sequential ID generation. We are testing the provided solution with number of test cases. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907908/google-app-engine-how-to-make-synchronized-actions-using-memcache-or-datastore

Comment: @Sashi All good as long as you **don't** use the solution provided by *smalex*. memcache is unreliable as a means to locking. All memcache values can be evicted at any time, so you're going to run into synchronization problems sooner or later. Sharded counters use memcache as well, but just for performance. The actual value is always backed by the datastore.